# What is this insect?

Tags: bugs, bug-identification

Found several insects like this one on my apartment, size of a tick and only has a tail, or tongue, or tentacle, or antenna, or head. Any idea of what it is?
[image]

Comment: As ticks come in many sizes, can you give a size in mm or fractions of an inch or something like that? And where in the world are you?

Answer (score 2):

That appears to be *Tinea pellionella*, or a Case-bearing Clothes Moth. A very similar image is found on [this website](https://www.moth-prevention.com/blogs/the-art-of-prevention/case-bearing-clothes-moth):

[image: moth]

[Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tinea_pellionella) on Tinea pellionella.